# How in project.pro call make files from nested folders with source code?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake, qtcore

I have create qt project and I have in project.pro file added new files and folders adn it compiles and works. I have external two directories with source code files and own CMakeLists.txt files and I need to add to qt project. How to add this ?

(I have tried to create to .so files and copy into /usr/local/lib and add to PATH and in project.pro I have added LIBS+= /usr/local/lib.
How to make project.pro uses make files for those two directory (to avoid to manually add every to project.pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could the following qmake function to run the cmake and etc. processes for you:

> [system(command)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#system-command)
>
> Executes the given command in a secondary shell. Succeeds if the command returns with a zero exit status; otherwise fails. You can check the return value of this function using a scope.
>
> For example:
>
> system(ls /bin):HAS_BIN=FALSE
>
> See also the replace variant of system().